# Setting bounds on multivariate data sets with possible multiple distribution types

Tags: multivariate-analysis, nonlinear-regression

**Summary:**
I've got data sets whose distribution seems to differ based on where on the x-axis the data occurs. Using some common distribution mean and std dev calculations do not produce acceptable limits for our purpose. The data for each sample can jump quite rapidly (i.e. exponentially) causing failures on tight limits for small horizontal deviations but little to no vertical deviations. Looser limits end up being too loose because they pass data that has deviated horizontally but deviated only just a bit vertically. How can I appropriately calculate and assign limits to this data given such extreme differences in slope and sample distribution?

Here you can see how most of our data tends to look.

[image: Image 1]

The x-axis is in the log domain, y-axis is linear, but the data is not. We always have a large peak like that and can sometimes have more. The data tends to rise and fall exponentially, but the distribution between samples does not seem uniform.

The distribution does not tend to be the same across all x-axis points. At points around the peak the data is distributed closest to a lognormal distribution, but around the flat areas it tends to be non-parametric. So how to calculate the mean and standard deviation when the distribution does not tend to be the same for all x-axis points?

Since quite a large percentage of points look to be lognormally distributed I tried calculating the mean and std dev then setting my process limits accordingly. We tend to set our limits to +/-6*sigma to achieve a Cpk of 2 per batch and 1.5 across all batches. I end up with limits like the two red curves in the first image above. Now, this is wrong to me. The upper limit seems ok, but the lower limit isn't right at all. I would never see curves that decrease in value like those 4 dips. If I were to see a curve that dipped at all in those areas it would either be a failure or considered an outlier, but it would never happen.

Noticing that the reason for the drastic negative dips was because I was multiplying by -6 I decided to just try putting the data in the log domain and performing normal distribution calculations, performing the multiplication in the log domain then converting back. This got me these limits:

[image: Image 2]

Looks better but still not perfect. However, as you may know, what I did also isn't a true lognormal calculation.

One of the biggest hurdles I'm trying to overcome with setting limits on data like this is that with such large peaks like this is that a very small change in x-axis curve with the exact same y-axis data could easily cause a failure if the limits are too tight because the slope around the peaks are so steep the y-axis difference is huge. But setting the limits to allow small x-axis changes would also allow large y-axis deviations to pass.

How can I appropriately set limits on data like this?